# @Prop and mongoose options is ignored in NestJS Nested Schema

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to build a Schema with a nested object in it. I want to set default values and required in the nested object but the options will get ignored.

**task.entity.ts**

```js
@Schema()
export class Task {
    @Prop({ required: true }) // Is working
    language: Language

    @Prop({ type: TaskContent, required: true })
    content: TaskContent
}

class TaskContent extends Document {
    @Prop({ required: true, default: "Hello World" }) // This prop is ignored.
    message: string
}

export type TaskDocument = Task & Document
export const TaskSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Task)
```

In my **task.service.ts**:

```js
const task = new this.taskSchema({
...dataFromPostRequest
})
const result = await task.save()
return result
```

How can I insert an object and use the @Prop from the nested object? I don't want to set it in one class. I would like to split the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build a Schema and use this as the type:

```js
@Schema()
export class Task {
    @Prop({ required: true })
    language: Language
 
    @Prop({ type: TaskContentSchema, required: true }) // Here
    content: TaskContent
}
 
class TaskContent extends Document {
    @Prop({ required: true, default: "Hello World" })
    message: string
}
 
const TaskContentSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(TaskContent) // Here
 
export type TaskDocument = Task & Document
export const TaskSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Task)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I really dislike it. It's not intuitive at all. Having a @Prop({required: true}) should be enough. Came across this using NestJS. Again thank you going to try your solution just hope that the responsible of this implementation agree or disagree on my opinion by commenting here.